# Filter table with dropdown

Tags: dropdown, table, phpmyadmin

I'm making two dropdowns of location and category to filter a table by internship location and category. I want to make it so that a user can select one or the other and it will still filter it. I also don't want a submit button. Rather the table should get filtered as soon as a user selects the dropdown. The database is in PHPMyAdmin btw. The code is just not working right now. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Search Bar using PHP</title>
   </head>
   <body>
 
      <form method="post" name="PostName" id="IdName">

             <label for="loc">Country/State: &nbsp;&nbsp; </label> 
         <select id="InternshipLocation" name="InternshipLocation" class ="InternshipLocation" onchange="filterTable()”>
            <option value="">Filter by location</option>
            <option value="Remote">Remote</option>
            <option value="Every state or most states">Every state or most states</option>
            <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
            <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
            <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
            <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
            <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
            <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
            <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
            <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
            <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
            <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
            <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
            <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
            <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
            <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
            <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
            <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
            <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
            <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
            <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
            <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
            <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
            <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
            <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
            <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
            <option value="New York">New York</option>
            <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
            <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
            <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
            <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
            <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
            <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
            <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
            <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
            <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
            <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
            <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
            <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
            <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
            <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
            <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
            <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
            <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
         </select>
         <label for="cat">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Category: &nbsp;&nbsp; </label>
         <select id="InternshipCategory" name="InternshipCategory" class ="InternshipCategory" onchange="filterTable()”>

            <option value="">Filter by category</option>
            <option value="Computer Science">Computer Science</option>
            <option value="Science">Science</option>
            <option value="Political Science">Political Science</option>
            <option value="Business/Marketing">Business/Marketing</option>
            <option value="Art, Music, Theater">Art, Music, Theater</option>
            <option value="All STEM fields">All STEM fields</option>
            <option value="Many fields">Many fields</option>
         </select>


      </form>
<button onclick="filterTable()">Submit</button>
 

        <?php

global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT InternshipName, InternshipLocation, InternshipCategory, InternshipLink, InternshipDeadline FROM InternshipDatabase");

echo "<style>";
echo "body {font-family: Arial;}";

echo ".table_container { padding: 10px 12px 0px 12px }";
echo ".table_container th { background-color:#50B4FC; color:white; font-weight:bold; width=”10%”; font-size:19px; border-left: 1px solid white;}";
echo "</style></head>";
echo "<body>";

echo "<div class=\"table_container\"><table id=”show” >";
echo "<tr><th style=\"padding-left:10px;\">Internship Name</th><th width=”20”>Internship Location</th><th width=”20”>Internship Category</th><th width=”20”>Internship Link</th><th width=”20”>Internship Deadline</th></tr>";
foreach ($result as $row) {

    echo "<tr><td width=”20”>" . $row->InternshipName . "</td><td width=”20”>" . $row->InternshipLocation . "</td><td width=”20”>" . $row->InternshipCategory . "</td><td width=”20”>" . $row->InternshipLink . "</td><td width=”20”>" . $row->InternshipDeadline ."</tr>";
}
echo "</table></div>";

?>
<script>
function filterTable() {
 var input, input2, filter, filter2, table, tr, td, i, test;
 input = document.getElementById("InternshipLocation");
 input2 = document.getElementById("InternshipCategory");
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 filter2 = input2.value.toUpperCase();
 table = document.getElementById("show");
 tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
 for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
   td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
   test = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[2]
   if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter.toUpperCase() &&test.innerHTML.toUpperCase() === filter2.toUpperCase())
     {
     tr[i].style.display = "";  
     }      
     else {
       tr[i].style.display = "none";
     }
   }      
 }
}


</script>
   </body>

</html>


<?php
   global $wpdb;
   
   if (!empty($_POST)) {
       $InternshipName = '%'.$_POST['InternshipName'].'%';
       $InternshipLocation = '%'.$_POST['InternshipLocation'].'%';
       $InternshipCategory = '%'.$_POST['InternshipCategory'].'%';
   
       $result = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM InternshipDatabase WHERE InternshipName LIKE %s AND `InternshipLocation` LIKE %s AND `InternshipCategory` LIKE %s", $InternshipName, $InternshipLocation, $InternshipCategory));
   
       if (!empty($result)) {
   ?>
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>InternshipName</th>
      <th>InternshipLocation</th>
      <th>InternshipCategory</th>
      <th>InternshipLink</th>
      <th>InternshipDeadline</th>
   </tr>
   <?php
      foreach ($result as $row) {
      ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row->InternshipName; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->InternshipLocation;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->InternshipCategory;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->InternshipLink;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row->InternshipDeadline;?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
      }
      ?>
</table>
<?php
   } else {
       echo "<p>Nothing found</p>";
   }
   }
   ?>
```

Picture:
[image]